# bypassing Telegram Bot API using a Google Apps Script web app

Tags: google-apps-script, http-post, telegram-bot

I try to build a Telegram bot using python and Telegram Bot API and since Telegram Bot API is censored in my country I found [this][1] script to bypass it by an app deployed using Google Apps Script.
but the problem is that it just sends text and not files, so I would like the web app to sort of redirect the files I'm sending to it to Telegram, This is a part of my python code:

```
fr = open("result.txt", "rb")
files = {"document": fr}
script_url = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycby20pnglgWTp4oV0tDTKuU87XmvkS6EZd-LTuoCmMM3Ge7PbGJ/exec?bot_token=' + token + '&method=sendDocument&args={"chat_id": ' + chat_id + '}'
requests.post(
    url=script_url,
    files=files
)
```

so I'm using a post method to send the file to the web app but on the web app side I don't know how to grab that file and send it to Telegram.
[1]: https://gist.github.com/manzoorwanijk/ee9ed032caedf2bb0c83dea73bc9a28e

Answer (score 1):

it's a better idea to just use a proxy to bypass censorship.

if you are using [python-telegram-bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot) then you can use this code below:

```
#put HTTP proxy url here
REQUEST_KWARGS = {'proxy_url': 'http://localhost:62612/'}

updater = Updater(token=TOKEN, use_context=True, request_kwargs=REQUEST_KWARGS)
```

you can use free tools like [lantern](https://lantern.io/en_US/index.html) or [tor](https://www.torproject.org) to setup your own proxy.